# Finding out if specific date is somewhere between two other dates for any year in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

So I'm making pretty simple console app for applying a discount for your flight depending on your case. In one case I can't add a discount if flight date is somewhere between YYYY/12/20 – YYYY(+1)/01/10 and between YYYY/03/20 – YYYY/04/10 but I'm not really sure how to approach that. I thought about specifying it like this:

```
DateTime springSeasonStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 03, 20);
DateTime springSeasonEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 04, 10);
```

and then check if my `flightDate` is somewhere between `springSeasonStart` and `springSeasonEnd`. If it is, the discount wouldn't apply but it doesn't really work because year can't be specified, only month and day can. So what can I do to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the start month is greater than end month. If it's greater, than it's next year and you need to add 1 year for the end date.

```
var date = new DateTime(2021, 12, 25); // flight date

// season start
var monthStart = 12;
var dayStart = 20;

// season end
var monthEnd = 1;
var dayEnd = 10;

var yearEndModifier = monthStart > monthEnd ? 1 : 0; // +1 if next year

var SeasonStart = new DateTime(date.Year, monthStart, dayStart);
var SeasonEnd = new DateTime(date.Year + yearEndModifier, monthEnd, dayEnd);

if (date >= SeasonStart && date <= SeasonEnd)
    Console.WriteLine("Discount");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No Discount");
```

In second case YYYY/03/20 – YYYY/04/10, yearEndModifier = 0 because start month is lesser than end month.

Comment: I didn't implement your exact solution but you have opened my eyes for it and kinda teached me new things about DateTime. It turns out I'm actually dumb :D Anyway thank you, everything works as it should for me :)